# How can I use home automation with hot water heating radiators?

Tags: thermostat, radiator, nest

My apartment (in a condo building) is currently using stationary PTACs (using electricity and hot water), which I'm planning to replace with a split-level A/C system (for cooling) and hot water radiators (for heating).

What I would like to accomplish is making all radiators controlled via some kind of smart thermostat (e.g. Nest). The way I understand it, each radiator should either have some wireless control natively or should be furnished with a smart valve.

Question is: what could you recommend as viable options for such setup. Googling around, I've found a bunch of smart valves on the market (e.g. [Danfoss](https://www.danfoss.com/en/products/smart-heating/dhs/smart-heating/), [Energenie](https://workswith.nest.com/company/energenie/energenie)), but they seem to be primarily available in Europe, with no official representation/sales in the US.

Are there any products in this area that are offered in the US and are geared toward US market? What do people use for smart radiators? Is there a different way to approach this problem?

Comment: Danfoss is an american company headquartered in Ames, Iowa USA

Comment: It might be, but they don't seem to sell any of their smart valves (Danfoss Eco) in the States. This is irrespective of the fact that they also have subpar reviews on Amazon.